# Spring @Recover Method Not Working

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to get a basic Spring retry sample to work.  I am using the code below from another post.

```
package com.example.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.EnableRetry;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Recover;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class RetryTest3Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(RetryTest3Application.class, args);
    Foo bean = context.getBean(Foo.class);

    try {
        bean.out("foo");
        System.out.println("Recovered");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not recovered: " + e);
    }

    try {
        bean.out("bar");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not recovered: " + e);
    }
}

@Bean
public Foo foo() {
    return new Foo();
}


public static class Foo {

    @Retryable(include = IllegalArgumentException.class, exclude = IllegalStateException.class, maxAttempts = 5)
    public void out(String foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
        if (foo.equals("foo")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

}

@Recover
public void connectionException(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Retry failure");
}

}
```

The output I receive is below.

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
Not recovered: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
bar
Not recovered: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Can someone tell me why the method connectionException is not being run?  It is annotated with @Recover and should be run when an IllegalArgumentException error is thrown.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try removing the `@Bean` method and annotate `Foo` class with `@Component` instead, so that Spring is responsible for creating the singleton instance, and can proxy/inject recovery handler logic.

Comment: It's working now both with the Bean and without.  The issue was the Recover method was outside of the Foo class. Thanks for your help @Andreas